# extjs align top of cell editor to top of row

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am using a gridpanel with cell editing, and I noticed all editors get vertically centered around a row. However, this becomes a problem especially with the htmleditor, as it has a rather large vertical profile and can get cut off by other elements. Is it possible to align the top of the editor with the top of the row instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around it with a bit of a hack (not supposed to access ownerCt), but it works.

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    listeners: {
        initialize: function(editor) {
            editor.ownerCt.alignTo(editor.ownerCt.boundEl, 'tl-tl');
            editor.ownerCt.alignment = 'tl-tl';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I was able to resolve it by applying body padding to both the parent and the child panels.

```
defaults: {
collapsible: true,
split: true,
bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
},
```

Hope that helps.